# Python built-in function

Tags: python

is there a build-in equivalent of such function in python:

```
def foo(a_func,a_list):
    if len(a_list)==2:
        return a_func(*[a_list])
    else:
        return a_func(a_list[0],foo(a_func,a_list[0:]))
```

in other words `foo(lambda x,y:x+y,[1,2,3,4])` would add `1+2+3+4`
and `foo(lambda x,y:x-y,[1,2,3,4])` would do `((1-2)-3)-4` etc.

And i know you can make it faster and prevent stack overflow ( :D ) but i think i remember such function but have no idea what the name is and dunno what to google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing the [`reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce); in Python 3 it has been moved to the [`functools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

> Apply *function* of two arguments cumulatively to the items of sequence, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value. For example, `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` calculates `((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`.

You can of course use any callable; the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) offers several handy options:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> import operator
>>> reduce(operator.add, [1,2,3,4])
10
>>> reduce(operator.sub, [1,2,3,4])
-8
```

Answer (score 3):

Its what that [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function is for!

> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable, from left to right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single value

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're looking for https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce (AKA https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce in Python 2), assuming there's a bug in your code and by `a_list[0:]` you actually mean `a_list[1:]` (otherwise you're looking for a never-ending loop:-).